# Get content of the container including parent in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get the innerHTML of an element with the parent itself. Since i am using element.innerHTML, it is returning the values that present inside the element and not the parent. So is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

**Note:** Please note that, i dont want to use any jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try - http://jsfiddle.net/PF68B/

```
var content = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode.innerHTML;
```

In case you want the content with the parent tag - http://jsfiddle.net/PF68B/1/

```
var content   = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode.innerHTML;
var parentTag = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase();
```

...

**UPDATE**

In case you need the parent node with all the attributes - http://jsfiddle.net/PF68B/4/

```
var content   = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode.innerHTML;
var parentTag = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase();

var el = document.getElementById("elem").parentNode;
var nodes=[], values=[];
for (var attr, i=0, attrs=el.attributes, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++){
    attr = attrs.item(i)
    nodes.push(attr.nodeName);
    values.push(attr.nodeValue);
}

var parentAttr  = '<' + parentTag;
for ( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
    parentAttr += ' ' + nodes[i] + '="' + values[i] + '"';
}
parentAttr += '>' + content + '</' + parentTag + '>';
```

Comment: Maybe he wants `<div>` and `</div>` too

Comment: @Mageek Maybe.. but that's not really clear from the question

Comment: I am thinking of a way to do it. It's quite complicated because if he write `<div id="foo" >` your way will display `<div>`

Comment: I *think* he wants from the id `foo` to get the result and not `elem`. (the id of the parent).

Comment: @Mageek Let's wait for the OP to make it clear what he *really* wants

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.outerHTML) property. But as it is not supported by old `Firefox`(version < `11.0`), you may use this script instead:

```
var tmpParent = document.createElement('div');
//Appending moves elements from its parents.
//For safety, clone was used instead of original node.
var cloneElem = yourDomElement.cloneNode();
cloneElem.innerHTML = yourDomElement.innerHTML;
tmpParent.appendChild( cloneElem );
//Markup
var elementMarkup = tmpParent.innerHTML;
console.log( elementMarkup );
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zx4PD/)

Comment: You should do `document.removeChild(tmpParent);` at the end to free the memory.

Comment: @Mageek Why do I need to `removeChild`,if there is no such child??!!! Where have you seen that I appended `tmpParent` to 'visible' dom element??!!!!

Comment: Oh, I tought you were appending